# Update column with value of other column which itself is updated all in same UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Consider this UPDATE-Statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_book 
SET return_date = planned_return_date, 
    planned_return_date = null 
WHERE book_id = 12;
```

I imagine this update works like this:

1. find the record in table *tbl_book* where the id matches, and set the value of
2. *return_date* to the value of *planned_return_date*
3. **and after that**, set the value of planned_return_date to NULL

Is my assumption correct?
Is the order of the SET-Clauses important?
I'd even guess, the column-reference in the assignment would always reflect the "old" records' value, right? In that case ordering would not matter ...

**Edit 2018-11-08:** Just to clarify, I've tagged my query with mysql and postgresql, since i need to know the answer for both.

Comment: The set clause order should not matter... However, some dbms products do things in their own ways. ("a = b, b = a" is expected to swap values, but try using different dbms products, some of them will make a = b and b = new a, i.e b...)

Comment: order doesn't matter. what makes no sense is your sentence: _the column-reference in the assignment would always reflect the "old" records' value_ what does it mean? the columns name will never change when you do an update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the SQL Standard, it *should* not use the updated values in any of those expressions. The pertinent text from the 2003 specification<sup>1</sup> states:

> The `<update source>` of each `<set clause>` is effectively evaluated for each row of T before any row of T is updated.

Where `<update source>` is the portion to the right of each assignment operator in the `SET` clause.

It would appear that MySQL may not follow the standard here, but I believe PostgreSQL and most other database products would. For MySQL, this is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. *This behavior differs from standard SQL.*
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

(My *emphasis*)

---

<sup>1</sup>Section 14.11 `<update statement: searched>` of Foundation. The choice of the 2003 standard was arbitrary, I don't expect this has much changed between versions of the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is:

```
UPDATE tbl_book 
    SET return_date = planned_return_date, 
        planned_return_date = null 
    WHERE book_id = 12;
```

When doing an `update`, think of the table as having two versions of each record -- let's call them "old" and "new", because that is common terminology used in triggers.

The value is being `set` in the *new* record.  The values on the other side of the `=` come from the *old* record.

Comment: I disagree. My observation is that if mysql detects that a column is used later in the sequence of set statements then the old. value is overwriiten before it is applied in the later set.

Comment: @P.Salmon - and this is the kind of problem that arises with people multi-tagging SQL questions with multiple products, when one of those products has a fairly poor track record (IMO) for following standards.

Comment: Tagging both MySQL and PostgreSQL is intended and on purpose, since I want and need to know the behavior in both of these DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Is the order of the SET-Clauses important? Yes order is a matter (for mysql)here cause if you do below query then

```
create table t 
(
id int, id1 int, id2 int
);
insert into t 
values 
(1,2,3),
 (1,2,4);
select * from t;

update t 
set id2=null,
id1=id2

where id1=2;
select * from t
```

output will be

```
id id1 id2
1  null null
1  null null
```

but if you do then out put will be below

```
update t 
set 
id1=id2,
id2=null

id id1 id2
1  3   null
1  4   null
```

So order is a matter in set clause

Comment: @eurotrash i checked it is for mysql

Comment: I agree with this assessment.